# ExceptionInInitializerError - ZBar Android

Tags: android, android-ndk

So I just created a branch of my Android app then rebuilt and ran it. All is good exception when I try and load up a screen which uses ZBar I get an `ExceptionInInitializerError` exception.

The culprit code seems to be the following:

```
static {

    System.loadLibrary("iconv");
}
```

I've tried debugging this but I can't seem to catch the above exception. After reading it seems it is linked to not being able to find a native library.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I solved it.

It was due to missing native code (.so files) in the folders { x86, armeabi, armeabi-v7a } in the Android projects `libs` folder.

For some reason subversion ignored these files so when I branched the code they didn't exist.

Comment: Yes! I checked out an Eclipse project, converted it to an Android Studio project, and ran into this very same issue. After the conversion the x86, armeabi, and armeabi-v7a folders will live in src/main/jniLibs. You'll need to dump the .so files there.